# What is the logic of showing Pay Later instructions on the Confirmation page

Tags: civievent, contribution-page, registration, paylater

can anyone shed light on why the Pay Later block is set to show on the Confirmation screen.

I am getting anecdotal evidence that some people think they have completed once they see the payment instructions - and i really can't see a reason why Pay Later show on Confirm at all.

The client who raised this does have some wording in Pay Later that increases the chance of someone thinking they have completed registration, and we will get that stripped out.

But looking at this did cause me to wonder why will add the noise/confusion of Pay Later at this screen.